# Android app with 2 user type login using parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to make an android app that have a two user types with parse.com i know how to make the log in page working for one user but I'm having difficulties finding a way to make it for two user types
here is my code that im trying to make it work

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0){
            mProgress.show();

            //Retrieve text from the EditText 
            txtUsername=username.getText().toString();
            txtPassword=password.getText().toString();

            ParseUser.logInInBackground(txtUsername, txtPassword, 
                    new LogInCallback(){
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e){
                    if(user != null && user.get){
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                        Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,AdministratorPage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Loged In As Administrator", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        if(user != null && user ){
                            mProgress.show();
                            Intent intent =new Intent(LoginActivity.this,UserPage.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            mProgress.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No such User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            username.setText("");
                            password.setText("");

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    });
```

Comment: How do you differentiate Admin users from Standard users in your `_User` class?

Comment: yes that is what im trying to do because i want the admin to have different access than the user. the user is only allowed to view the content of the database while the admin is allowed to write to the database and even allowed to add and delete users

Answer (score 1):

You could add another column to _User class of boolean type then after a successful login you could check if the user is admin or user

```
if(user!=null && (user.getBoolean("isAdmin")== true))
```

like

```
public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e){
                if(user != null &&  (user.getBoolean("isAdmin")== true)) ){
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,AdministratorPage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Loged In As Administrator", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }else{
                    if(user != null && user ){
                        mProgress.show();
                        Intent intent =new Intent(LoginActivity.this,UserPage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No such User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        username.setText("");
                        password.setText("");

                    }
                }
```

Comment: You seem to have just copied his code without implementing your `isAdmin` property.

Comment: this does not work because the method isAdmin is not implemented i created a  column from parse but when i try to use it it gives me The method isAdmin() is undefined for the type ParseUser

Comment: updated the answer... and btw try to data type it as boolean..hope my answer helps

Answer (score 0):

```
public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e){
                    if(user != null && user.getBoolean("isAdmin")==true ){
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                        Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,AdministratorPage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Loged In As Administrator", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        if(user != null && user.getBoolean("isAdmin")==false){
                            mProgress.show();
                            Intent intent =new Intent(LoginActivity.this,UserPage.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            mProgress.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No such User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            username.setText("");
                            password.setText("");

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    });
```